# Load an external element with .load() targeting an <a> tag's parent

Tags: jquery, load, parent

I'm trying to load in some external content using the jQuery .load event, which is all fine. my problem is that I'm trying to select/target a parent element of an 'a' tag which contains a certain string of text...

My current code is as follows:

```
$('.actionlink').live('click',function() {
    $('<div id="info" />').load('/pageURLhere .container a:contains("string of text"):parent',
function() { 
     .......
```

Currently the code works fine in bringing in the 'a' tag that contains the matched string - but the ":parent" seems to be completely ignored - it doesn't even break the script.

Is this just to complex a selector combination or is my set-up wrong?

The external page structure is something like this:

```
<div>
    <a href"#">string of text</a>
</div>
```

and I want to select and load in the div but I can only target the 'a' tag by means of a matched string.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your page is tiny because the performance of that selector is going to be aweful.  I'd do two things:

1. Add some sort of ID to the element you're wanting to select rather than basing it on content.  If you know the content, you should be able to add an ID and select against that instead.
2. Once you've got the source brought back, chain your selectors with operations.  Once you have your loaded page element, just do a normal operation against it rather than combining your complex selectors up front.

EDIT (more info):
Your issue is likely due to how jQuery constructs the page fragments: http://api.jquery.com/load/

My bet is that by the time it gets to :parent it's already made a selection of content and there's no more parent to get.

Comment: thanks but part of my problem is that I can only use the text content of the link as my basis of selection... but I need to grab the container div around it. I'd tried running script on the external page to add an ID this div but it doesn't seen like the live load call recognizes it (unless I did something wrong there).

I don't follow your point 2. but I understand what you are saying about no parent available by the time text selection has been made.

Not great with javascript/jquery so any other suggestions on solving this problem?

Comment: Ah! solved. Didn't realize I could search the container div for the text string ANYWHERE within it... I was trying to be too specific, so this works fine (...  .container:contains("string of text")  ...)